# PHP SimpleXML error

Tags: php, simplexml

I have a big problem (at least for me ;)) with SimpleXML parser. The error is:

`Warning: simplexml_load_file(): file.meta:16: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name in index.php on line 89`
`Warning: simplexml_load_file(): <335> in index.php on line 89`
`Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in index.php on line 89` 
`Warning: simplexml_load_file(): file.meta:18: parser error : expected '>' in index.php on line 89`
 
`Warning: simplexml_load_file(): in index.php on line 89` 
`Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in index.php on line 89` 
`Warning: simplexml_load_file(): file.meta:18: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: Sequence line 15 and unparseable in index.php on line 89`
`Warning: simplexml_load_file(): in index.php on line 89` 
`Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in index.php on line 89` 
`Warning: simplexml_load_file(): file.meta:19: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name in index.php on line 89`
`Warning: simplexml_load_file(): <337> in index.php on line 89`
 
`Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in index.php on line 89` 
`Warning: simplexml_load_file(): file.meta:21: parser error : expected '>' in index.php on line 89` 
`Warning: simplexml_load_file(): in index.php on line 89` 
`Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in index.php on line 89` 
`Warning: simplexml_load_file(): file.meta:21: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: MetaAttack line 2 and unparseable in index.php on line 89` 
`Warning: simplexml_load_file(): in index.php on line 89`
`Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in index.php on line 89`
`Warning: simplexml_load_file(): file.meta:21: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document in index.php on line 89` 
`Warning: simplexml_load_file(): in index.php on line 89`
`Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in index.php on line 89` 
`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in index.php on line 97`

I've googled it but got nothing. I searched for XML tag declaration also (maybe its forbidden to declare a number tag) but found nothing. Below you can find my xml (.meta) file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                                                                                                                                   
<MA>
    <Count>
        3
    </Count>
    <Duration>
        34
    </Duration>
    <End>
        1315815814
    </End>
    <Start>
        1315815780
    </Start>
    <Sequence>
        <335>
            1315815794
        </335>
        <337>
            1315815814
        </337>
        <336>
            1315815804
        </336>
    </Sequence>
</MA>
```

On line 89:

```
$ma = simplexml_load_file("file.meta");
```

Any answer is appreciated. Thanks in advance. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using numbers in tag names is ok - but starting with number is not ok...

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp

## XML Naming Rules

XML elements must follow these naming rules:

- Names can contain letters, numbers, and other characters
- Names cannot start with a number or punctuation character
- Names cannot start with the letters xml (or XML, or Xml, etc)
- Names cannot contain spaces

Any name can be used, no words are reserved.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have numbers as element names. From the [Wikipedia article on XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML):

> The element tags are case-sensitive; the beginning and end tags must match exactly. Tag names cannot contain any of the characters !"#$%&'()*+,/;<=>?@[]^`{|}~, nor a space character, and cannot start with -, ., **or a numeric digit.**

Answer (score 0):

Well definetely you should not name your tags starting with a number. This is a problem here. I would recommend you to change XML structure as it's not convinient right now at all to deal with. For instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MA>
    <Count>3</Count>
    <Duration>34</Duration>
    <End>1315815814</End>
    <Start>1315815780</Start>
    <Sequence>
        <value index="335">1315815794</value>
        <value index="336">1315815814</value>
        <value index="337">1315815804</value>
    </Sequence>
</MA>
```

Then you would proccess this XML pretty easy with the code:

```
$ma = simplexml_load_file("file.meta");
$sequence = $ma->xpath('Sequence/value');

foreach ($sequence as $el)
{
    echo "Index: {$el['index']}, value: $el <br>";
}
```

Which will output:

```
Index: 335, value: 1315815794 
Index: 336, value: 1315815814 
Index: 337, value: 1315815804
```